# Prepared statement security while fetching

Tags: mysqli, sql-injection

I just don't get it.  How is a prepared statement more safe than a non-prepared statement for fetching data.  I am not talking about writing to the database, only fetching data.  I cant see how userFname and userLname is any more safe than userEmail and userPassword.  Thanks in advance.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT userFname, userLname FROM users WHERE userEmail = ? and userPassword = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userEmail, $userPassword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($userFname, $userLname);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            //Remember first name, last name, and email
            $_SESSION['Email']=$userEmail;
            $_SESSION['Fname']=$userFname;
            $_SESSION['Lname']=$userLname;
            $stmt->close();
            //go to dashboard page
            header ("location: dashboard.php");    
        }
        $error2="Email and Password do not match, please try again."; 
    }
```

Comment: SQL injections just exploit improperly escaped variables in order to modify your query. They can still happen even if you don't write anything to the database.

Comment: Is userFname any safer using a prepared statement.  It is not binded, even in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one huge Babylonian Tower in the field of SQL injection.

Everybody's using a dozen of words, hardly understood their meaning and - worse of that - having their own idea on the meaning at all.

> **Example:** 99% of PHP users will tell you that data have to be "escaped". While technically escaping is a very special action, **insufficient** for the protection in one case while **useless** and harmful in another.

The same goes for every other word from the list of "sanitizing", "filtering", "escaping", "prepared statements" and the like.

Thus, figuratively speaking, every conversation turns to a dispute between the blind and the deaf.

**Exactly the same** goes for the thing called `"input input"`. It's another a source of many confusions and - worse of that - vulnerabilities. While, in its most obvious meaning, **it has absolutely nothing to do with SQL injection** at all.

So, reading recommendations from various sites keep in mind that you have to understand the terminology and - more than that - understand what the author meant.

Back to your question, the answer is fairly simple:

1. Prepared statements have to be used for the **everything** that moves into query dynamically.
2. For the case where prepared statements cannot be used, whitelisting have to be used instead.

These rules are fairly simple to memorize. So - **do not add any complexity in them!** Do not bother your self with questions like "Where did this data come from?" "In what query it goes?" - they are of no use and error prone.

To follow these rules is not that easy, but that's another topic.

Comment: ("SELECT userFname FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?")...Great!  So trim all input, whitelist userFname (FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL - Remove all characters except letters, digits and !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@.[]. don't worry about userEmail and then htmlspecialchars() for all output.  Hope I got it right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a training instructor for MySQL.  I was telling a group of attendees about the risks of SQL injection, and one guy said, "show me."

He handed me his laptop, which had a browser open to the login screen of his website (actually it was just a QA instance of it).

Knowing nothing about his code or his database, I made an educated guess that he had an SQL query like yours, that he wasn't using query parameters, and that he wasn't escaping input properly.  I entered a string for login including close-quote and some boolean expression, and then I entered random keystrokes for the password.

His application authenticated my bogus login, and I was in.

I don't think it's appropriate to show you exactly how I did it, but it isn't rocket science -- minimal knowledge of boolean algebra is all you need.

But the point is that SQL injection of a SELECT query can allow illicit actions, just like SQL injection of a statement that modifies data.

---

Re your comments on bad info:

It's true that query parameters can't be spoofed, and there's no need to use escaping functions.

But query parameters work only in places where you would normally use a single string, date, or numeric literal.  Query parameters can't be used for dynamic table names, column names, lists of values, SQL keywords, expressions, etc.  For those, you still need to interpolate application variables into your SQL query *before* calling prepare(), like old-school, unsafe programming.  Therefore you still need to be careful to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.  The best way to do that is to **whitelist** content before including it in SQL queries.

See my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) for more information, or a [webinar of me presenting it](http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-07-25-sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) (free, but requires registration).  I also wrote about SQL injection in a chapter of my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: I am using prepared statements to write to the database, but I still need to use prepared statements to fetch data?  Thanks.

Comment: As Bill mentioned, you need to sanitize the input, be it writing or fetching. In his case, login is retrieving the data (SELECT whether the user and password is correct, there can be no need to write to DB), yet in this case he can login without having the correct user and password.

Comment: Many programming websites say that there is no need to sanitize user input when using prepared statements, but like you both said, this is not the case.  Many people like myself probably have a false sense of security when using prepared statements.  Thanks

Comment: An example of bad info:  A quick google search comes up with this; *Using the methods in the steps below, you will not need to use any other SQL injection filtering techniques such as mysql_real_escape_string(). This is because with prepared statements it is not possible to do conventional SQL injection.*

Comment: user2734634: most site authors have no clue. Keep that in mind. Also, people in general have no idea on the words like "sanitizing", "filtering", "escaping", "prepared statements" and such, taking them as one (which is obviously wrong) yet each bear their own meaning. Take a comment from @rcs for example: he says "sanitize" while prepared statement is anything but "sanitize".